# Call an abstract method with prototype

Tags: javascript, typescript, abstract-class, typescript-typings

I have an abstract class with an abstract method. I discovered that Typescript won't throw any error if I called the method with `prototype` and `call`. For exmaple:

```
abstract class Human{
    age: string;
    constructor(age: string){
        this.age = age;
    }
    abstract name(): void
}

class Human1 extends Human{
    constructor(age: string){
        super(age);
        this.name()
        
    }
name(): void {
    Human.prototype.name.call(this); // this is allowed despite that name is undefined/abstract
    let a = "do something";
    }
}

let a = new Human1("23")
```

Is there a way to make Typescript throw an error here?

Comment: The error is not calling the abstract method, but that the concrete class doesn't implement the method. A class should either implement all abstract methods or itself be abstract

Comment: Typescript should tell you "Non-abstract class 'Derived' does not implement inherited abstract member 'getName' from class 'Base'."

Comment: But I implement the abstract method here, or what do you mean and how to get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I discovered that Typescript won't throw any error if I called the method with `prototype` and `call`.

Yes, TypeScript is pretty bad at typing prototype objects. It thinks that `Human.prototype` has the type `Human`<sup>1</sup>, and for that it only considers the public interface. The `abstract` modifier is only affecting subclass implementations.

> Is there a way to make Typescript throw an error here?

Yes, don't use `.call` to call the parent method. There's the `super` keyword for that:

```
name(): void {
    super.name(); // this errors
    let a = "do something";
}
```

<sup>([playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgEgVwLbADsBvAKAXIWAHMBTALgUigEsCqBuMi2AewKezweUABTV6jaKyoBKUhQUIIAC2ZgAdOIQBeSrU4KAvl3KgmcRAWC4aImQwBuPZgBMSxkijQYc+AgEYEGgAPCBoCFx88QnluPgEhUXEGJmk5E0UwbAAHGiTaGQNFchU1dSsbOwoM4wUK23sEJ1cEWOKs3Khy6wb2BAB6fqVVDDyoYTAMhWQaRGAdBAAiFx5GHhtStkWi8mMPGbmFghoAdyxogJFFgCYAZkWZEhJfQnVs8YgeCABPXPVefjQQSfKDPC5vD5fX40TS0IA))</sup>

This does not compile but throws the error "*Abstract method 'name' in class 'Human' cannot be accessed via super expression. (ts 2513)*" as expected.

<sub>1: Notice also that it thinks `Human.prototype.age` is a number, and that `Human.prototype.constructor` is any `Function` and not `typeof Human`.</sub>

Comment: You might want to link to [ms/TS#44181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44181) in this answer